# How to install Cloudera Flume onto the linux Gentoo (EngineYard)

Tags: chef-infra, gentoo, cloudera, engineyard, flume

asking if anybody knows some options to install Cloudera Flume  on the linux Gentoo EngineYard's instance through the portage (emerge)

Or chef recipe to compile flume.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Gentoo does not support maven for building packages so you probably wont be able to find an ebuild for Cloudera Flume.  You basically have 2 options.  Create a binary ebuild based on the pre-built binaries or build it your self outside of portage.  For more information on creating your own ebuild see: http://www.gentoo.org/proj/en/devrel/handbook/handbook.xml?part=2&chap=1